# Can multiple Apps share microphone in ios？

Tags: android, ios

In Live Game Streaming, only using cellphone I find both Game app like Honor of Kings and live streaming app can use microphone recording simultaneously. but it does not work in Android

Expect to know why it works in iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it possible
in iOS using operating system's audio session management.more then one app will use microphone simultaneously.